# After small code change 'awk' prints header and blank lines, (not header repeated)

Tags: shell, awk

`data-file` content:

```
             k = 0.1667 0.0962 0.0000 (  4922 PWs)   bands (ev):

-7.1689  -7.1043  -6.1682  -6.0658   1.1309   1.5196   3.0894   3.1087
 3.3846   3.7588   4.2143   4.2220   4.3882   4.4011   5.1222   5.6229
 5.9506   6.2078   8.4442   8.8100   8.8150   8.8529   8.9070   9.0070
 9.5911   9.6311  13.5626  14.3720  15.0169  15.2435 
  end1
  end2
  end3
```

I have tried two `awk` commands on this data...

1.

```
awk -F'=' '/[[:blank:]]k/{w=w""$2}; { print w}' data-file
```

Output:

```
     0.1667 0.0962 0.0000             matrix :
     0.1667 0.0962 0.0000             matrix :
     0.1667 0.0962 0.0000             matrix :
     0.1667 0.0962 0.0000             matrix :
     0.1667 0.0962 0.0000             matrix :
     0.1667 0.0962 0.0000             matrix :
     0.1667 0.0962 0.0000             matrix :
     0.1667 0.0962 0.0000             matrix :
     0.1667 0.0962 0.0000             matrix :
```

2.

```
awk -F'=' '/[[:blank:]]k/{w=w""$2}; { print w;w=""}' data-file
```

Output:

```
0.1667 0.0962 0.0000 (  4922 PWs)   bands (ev):











(Eight newlines are printed after that.)
```

With the second command the searched pattern is printed only once, but with more empty lines.   But the first command the pattern is printed nine times.  What is the difference between the `awk` commands: why did it print more times, and why the empty line are printed?
***How to suppress printing these empty lines?***

Comment: Well, the main difference between the two scripts is this: `w=""`. Can you guess what it means?

Comment: Also, remember that in `awk`, *a rule without a pattern is applied to every record* - see [Getting Started with awk](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Getting-Started.html#Getting-Started)

Comment: Hi michael, awk does searching upto end of file. #of line is 9. at 1st line awk finds pattern and prints it. but when it goes to 2nd 3rd.. lines once agin it prints pattern. so in  adding w="" deletes content in w.  but in second command it prints empty line i want to suppress it how to do it

Comment: Also, `data-file` is 6 lines long, the output is 9 lines.  There must be at least one old version of `data-file` left over.  To see six-line output, remove the `**` at the end of the two `awk` commands.

Comment: @agc The `**` isn't part of the command, that's formatting left behind while editing.

Comment: this is problem with posting i tried to bold the commands but nit successful my commands are same thing as in the post but without ** at the end .        also that the datafile contains data end1 end2 end3 statements in successive lines, these also not printed in post

Comment: I'm confused about what you are trying to achieve: what is your actual input data and desired output? I don't see `4922 PWs` or `bands (ev)` anywhere in your original snippet. If you want help, it's best to ask direct - instead of asking an elliptical question about why one command produces a different output from another command when neither command (apparently) produces what you want

Comment: i am sorry steeldriver. i committed mistake in pasting snippets now i have corrected my question. at a time i worked in three terminals that is i confused

Comment: Trailing `**`s are now removed, (as soon as the edit gets through the queue anyway).  Brings up a new question, since with the above `awk` code 6 lines of input won't produce 9 lines of output.   What number does `wc -l < data-file` print?

Comment: `print w`, where w is `""`, is the same as `print ""`, which prints an empty line. If you don't want to print anything, you can use an `if` statement so that `print` will only be executed under whatever conditions you choose.

Answer (score 1):

> why did it print more times

Your `awk` script has an action with no pattern, which means that it will be carried out for each input line. If you don't want to print the pattern you search for several times, then **don't do that**.

> why the empty line are printed

Because you print `w` and then set `w=""`. Then you print `w` again for each input line.

The obfuscated question makes it hard to tell, but I **guess** you want to do this:

```
awk -F'=' '/[[:blank:]]k/{ print $2 }' data-file
```

Comment: yes i understand that. i want to know how to stop printing newlines . what commend i have to add in my awk

Comment: @MuthuValliNayagam If you don't want the empty lines, please edit the question to mention that.

Comment: hi jigglynaga i have changed my question

Answer (score 0):

Those lines are printed because `{print w;w=""}` happens every time, even if there is nothing in `w`.  If you only want to print the non-empty lines, you will have to make that `{print...}` action conditional on `w` having some content.

Conveniently, `awk` considers the empty string to be `false` and all non-empty strings to be `true` (["True and False in `awk`"](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Truth-Values.html)).  So you can get what you need by adding `w` as the pattern:

```
awk -F'=' '/[[:blank:]]k/{w=w""$2}; w { print w;w=""}'
```